# Change page formatting for all worksheets to fit on paper

Tags: performance, vba, excel, layout

I have the below code that will loop through all worksheets of the workbook and will format each sheet by deleting, change page orientation, page margins and be able to print each sheet on 1 paper.

The below code it's working but it takes time as the `Call editingPropertiesis` quite long and takes time to go through it for all sheets.

Is there a better way to write the editingProperties sub?

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet

Public Sub editAllSheets()
'
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
Dim myResult As VbMsgBoxResult

myResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to edit all sheets in this workbook?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton1, "Edit workbook")
If myResult = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Call editingProperties
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Next ws
        Sheets.Select
        MsgBox "Please note:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. All the sheets are selected." & vbNewLine & "2. Proceed with print preview to view and print all reports." & vbNewLine & "3. To print preview or print only 1 report of this workbook you need to click on a different sheet to deselect all.", vbInformation, "Process Completed!"

    Exit Sub '<--- exit here if no error occured
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

End Sub

Private Sub editingProperties()

    Columns("A:E").Select
    Range("A4").Activate
    Selection.UnMerge
    Columns("B:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1:B2").Select
    Selection.Merge
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
         Cells.Select
         Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
         Range("A3").Select

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to reduce the above code to something smaller:

```
    Public Ws As Worksheet

    Public Sub editAllSheets()

    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
    '
    Dim myResult As VbMsgBoxResult

    myResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to edit all sheets in this workbook?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton1, "Edit workbook")
    If myResult = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

       On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

            For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            'Ws.Activate
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
             editingProperties Ws
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Next Ws
            Sheets.Select
            MsgBox "Please note:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. All the sheets are selected." & vbNewLine & "2. Proceed with print preview to view and print all reports." & vbNewLine & "3. To print preview or print only 1 report of this workbook you need to click on a different sheet to deselect all.", vbInformation, "Process Completed!"

        Exit Sub '<--- exit here if no error occured
    ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
        MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

    End Sub

    Private Sub editingProperties(Ws As Worksheet)

Dim Rng As Range

With Ws
       .Columns("A:F").UnMerge

    Set Rng = Application.Union(.Columns("B:C"), _
                                .Columns("E:F"), _
                                .Columns("J:H"), _
                                .Columns("N:P"), _
                                .Columns("T"))
        Rng.Delete

       .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
       .Range("A1:B2").Merge

   End With


     With Ws.PageSetup
            .PrintArea = ""
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftFooter = ""
            .CenterFooter = ""
            .RightFooter = ""
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1

        End With
    End Sub
```